# Data representation in rich AJAX user interfaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I recently starting dabbling in AJAXy UIs and quickly ran into an issue. Let's say that you've got a table with a set of rows and you want to mirror client side actions on the server. So for example on the server side you could do this.

```
print('<table>')
for(item in data)
    print('<tr>')
    print('<td>')
    print(item)
    print('</td>')
    print('<td>')
    print('<a href="delete?item=' + item + '">Delete</a>')
    print('</td>')
    print('</tr>')
print('</table>')
```

In javascript that can be achieved by building a similar link when building the table, maybe a `javascript:deleteItem(item)`. But what if you could just explicitly tag a row with metadata that holds its item name and from the context of the link clicked figure out the item? [JQuery metadata](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/metadata) allows this functionality, but surely this isn't the only/best way of achieving it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of jQuery also supports [html5 data attribute](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/). This would be my recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

As already said you can use HTML5 custom data attributes, you could do something like:

```
<div class="deleteButton" data-id="SOME_UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER">DELETE</div>
```

And then use a general function like the next one to manage clicks on the delete buttons:

```
$('.deleteButton').click(function() {
    // through $(this).attr('data-id') you can
    // get that unique identifier you previously set
    // and do something with it
}
```